# Kafka Streams joining streams - design stratergy

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I am trying to join 2 streams, where

Stream 1 has events A, B, C.

Stream 2 has events D, E, F.

I want to join 1 & 2 on the occasion that I see event B and D from 1 & 2 respectively.

So far the approach I have is - create another intermediate stream `1' and 2'` (1Prime & 2Prime) such that that only contain events B & D. Create a join on `1' and 2'`.

Is this the only approach or are there better ways to handle this?

Comment: Are you planning to use kStreams or Processor API?

Comment: Planning to use kStreams

Comment: Joins in Kafka Streams are based on keys. Also, your example is unclear -- why do you want to join B and D, but not A and D for example (ie, what is your actual join condition?) -- currently Kafka Streams DSL supports key-based equi-joins.